# Avoid second click in silverlight button MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, double-click

I've seen I have a problem with several users that use to double-click in buttons.

I have several buttons bound to commands that launch many actions.

For example there are two windows that communicate between them through a mediator so when I click "close the other window", the bound command sends a "CloseTheOtherWindowMessage". The problem is that when a user makes double click it tries to close the window a second time and, as expected, it crashes.

I've tried to set the window BusyIndicator as IsBusy when I press the button but my finger is quicker than MVVM and it still let me double-click before it starts showing the BusyIndicator.

I've found many examples of how to only admit double click in MVVM using interaction.Behaviors but I want just the opposite. Is there any example or other good and general solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why is it "as expected" when it crashes? A crash should never be "as expected".
2. Your finger shouldn't be "quicker than MVVM". The Dispatcher thread always acts deterministically and sequentially. Do you use a multi-threaded approach?
3. In the command's `Execute` method or handler, raise its `CanExecuteChanged` event, and the binding engine will immediately call `CanExecute(...)`. Make it so that this method will return `false` the second time. Maybe use a timer, or, better yet, you can logically determine by your view model state alone that the action is not possible right now (i.e. because `IsOtherStuffAvailable` is currently `false`).

Comment: 1. It is "as expected" because when the second "close" arrives, the window has already been closed.
2. I'm as surprised as you are. On fact, if I set a breakpoint it works good (the BusyIndicator starts and I can't click the button the second time).
3. That's the only option I have in mind but I don't want to change all my application buttons with this problem (it's a huge application and I was looking for something more general if it exists).
Thanks for your answer!